# navbar: how to avoid stacking of menuitems on collapse?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a navbar and - because there is sufficient space even on xs screens - want to remove just the titles of my options and show their icons instead when the width gets sufficiently small. So I placed the text in `span`s with `class="hide-xs"` - and indeed, it disappears on xs. However, on xs, every menu-item gets its own row, whereas I'd like them to float.

Sample [here](https://codepen.io/MBaas/pen/VzbMRy)

I am hoping it can be achieved with CSS, but don't know how. As coworker commented this would require JS...and left, so I have no idea what he meant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this

```
.nav>li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```